# MySQL - Group order without sorting

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm trying to optimize a query where I've concluded that the order doesn't matter. So I'm trying to remove `ORDER BY` in the following scenario:

```
SELECT item, price FROM supplydemand
    GROUP BY item
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Here's what's going on: the table supplydemand keeps track of prices for various items. For every item I have 4 or 5 different prices, and therefore different rows. The query above gives me the "oldest" price per item. The grouping is done on item, and the ascending timestamp gives me the oldest row. This query works correctly.

I've noticed that as long as I have the oldest price, I don't actually care if the returned rows are sorted. So I wanted to get rid of `ORDER BY`. Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT item, price, timestamp FROM supplydemand
    GROUP BY item
    HAVING timestamp = MIN(timestamp)
```

The query above should result in an identical data except not sorted. The `MIN` inside of `HAVING` has to rely on the `GROUP` therefore comparing the timestamp of every grouped item to the oldest timestamp within the group.

**The Problem**
The second query returns less rows. For some reason certain rows are missing from the second query, and I cannot figure out why. The remaining rows return identical price, but I'm missing almost 20% of the data.

Comment: `MIN(timestamp)` is global for the whole table.

Comment: Then I would receive only 1 row or so. MIN() operates on the `GROUP`, not globally

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that my *original* query is actually wrong. It groups first, then sorts, which isn't what I wanted

Comment: You are correct.  Your first query doesn't give you the desired result.  Your second query will.  However, if you have an item with two different prices and the same timestamp, you might get different prices for that item each time you run the query.  You might want to put a MAX() or MIN() around price just to keep the results consistent in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT item, price, timestamp
FROM SupplyDemand
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT item, MIN(timestamp) AS minimumtimestamp FROM SupplyDemand
) AS minimums
ON minimums.item = SupplyDemand.item AND minimums.minimumtimestamp = supplydemand.timestamp
```

would be one way.

Comment: Aside from your choice of capitalization this is the same query that I've just concluded for myself. As a side note - the speed up was insignificant for my size table.

Comment: If scaling is an issue then an index on Item and timestamp, should sort it. Doubt you are going to see a siginificant performance increase until you hit a fair volume of data though.

Comment: I usually throw indices on anything that might be a query filter